# Is hive, Pig or Impala used from command line only?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, impala

I am new to Hadoop and have this confusion. Can you please help?

Q. How Hive, Pig or Impala are used in practical projects? Are they used from command line only or from within Java, Scala etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use Hive and Pig from the command line, or run scripts written in their language.

Of course it is possible to call(/build) these scripts in any way you like, so you could have a Java program build a pig command on the fly and execute it.

The Hive (and Pig) languages are typically used to talk to a Hive database. Besides this, it is also possible to talk to the hive database via a link (JDBC/ODBC). This could be done directly from anywhere, so you could let a java program make a JDBC connection to talk to your Hive tables.

Within the context of *this* answer, I belive everything I said about the Hive language also applies to Impala.